# Проверка на наличие недопустимых значений

Tags: c#, строки

Мне нужно сделать проверку строки, в ней должны быть только английские буквы и цифры, больше ничего. Просто работаю с клиентскими данными.Спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Традиционно для этих целей используют *регулярные выражения*:

```
Regex.IsMatch(@"[a-zA-Z0-9]+", "abc97SDF") == true
```

Здесь шаблон `[a-zA-Z0-9]` — совпадает с любым символом от a до z, от A до Z и от 0 до 9.

Квантор `+` показывает, что символов должно быть не меньше одного. Больше — можно.

Впрочем, язык регулярных выражений довольно сложен. Для простых задач можно использовать простые проверки. В нашем случае хорошо подходит LINQ:

```
const string suitableChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

"abc193SDF".All(c => suitalbeChars.Contains(c)) == true
```

Этот код будет работать не очень быстро, потому что поиск в строке `suitableChars` пропорционален её длине. Вместо *массива* символов мы можем использовать хеш-таблицу символов:

```
var suitableChars = new HashSet<char>("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");

"abc193SDF".All(c => suitalbeChars.Contains(c)) == true
```

Comment: есть ещё вариант типа `if ((c >= 'a' && c<='z') || (c >= 'A' && c<='Z') || (c >= '0' && c<='9')) return true;`

Comment: Можно через Except. Там за "кулисами" преобразование в HashSet происходит.