# Проверка JSON на зашифрованность

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть ли споcоб проверить JSON на предмет зашифрованности контента ?
У меня есть контроллер, который принимает в себя архив, распаковывает его, дешифрует содержимое и возращает контент на фронт.

JSONы в архивах могут быть как шифрованные, так и не шифрованные.

Мне нужно их как-то различать. Т.к. шифрованные JSONы нужно на фронте запретить редактировать.

А в контроллере и те и другие файлы проходят по одному и тому же пути. Отличить одно от других не получается

Примеры файлов:
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/dqgG/7C3ka8YxZ
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Tf9h/AG1ErjtZq

Comment: Как вариант, я думаю пытаться читать файл и смотреть по контенту, если первый символ "{", то файл не шифрован. Но не факт, что шифрованный файл удастся открыть и почитать.
Но все же, может есть способ получше...?

Comment: *"Отличить одно от других не получается"* - вот вы сами же на свой вопрос ответили. *"не факт, что шифрованный файл удастся открыть и почитать"* - эмм.. а вы точно программист? Почти любой файл можно открыть и прочитать в бинарном виде.

Comment: Приведите пример шифрованного и не шифрованного json

Comment: @SwaD я добавил примеры файлов в пост

Comment: @Kromster с бэком оч мало работаю. Вот и много моментов не знаю наверняка )
Но если читается в бинарном виде, то гуд. По контенту можно тогда попробовать различать.
А иных способов нет ?

Comment: Любой способ различия содержимого будет открывать это содержимое и анализировать его. Например, как вы сами сказали - читать первые НН байт и смотреть их значения (наличие первого `{` итп)

Comment: Вы можете Regex-ом их проверить: [здесь уже отвечали на подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/945821/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)